# Bitwise Operations using shift registers

Tags: c++, arduino, bit-manipulation, avr

I am getting started learning more about AVR ATMEGA programming.
Reading an article about the inner workings of Arduinos, I am learning how the `shiftOut` method is structured. I am kind of familiar with bitwise operations so far, but I have an expression I do not understand yet:

```
void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST) {
            PORTD |= !!(val & (HIGH << i)); 
        } else {
            PORTD |= !!(val & (HIGH << (7 - i)));           
        }   
        PORTB |= (HIGH << clockPin);
        PORTB ^= (HIGH << clockPin);
    }
}
```

The line `PORTD |= !!(val & (HIGH << i));` is not 100% clear to me. I understand that I set the i-th bit High on PORTD but what does the `!!` mean and `val&(HIGH <<i))`

I know this might sound basic, but can you please help me out?

Comment: looks broken to me.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This is the original code of the Arudino `wiring_shift.c` except that 1 has been changed for HIGH

Comment: I would need to do more research to find out what is going maybe this ghee whiz C code that could have been done in a more readable manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HIGH 0
int main ( void )
{

    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char PORTD;
    unsigned char val;

    PORTD=0;

    for(val=3;val;val<<=1)
    {
        printf("0x%02X\n",val);
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            PORTD |= !!(val & (HIGH << i));
            printf("PORTD 0x%02X\n",PORTD);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I dont know what your definition of HIGH is but since they are walking it 8 time across a byte i assume it is one bit, it is perhaps allowing for positive or negative logic on the port, so could be a 0 or 1 I am thinking.

I get all 0x01 if HIGH is 1 and all 0x00 if HIGH is 0.  so it doesnt seem to be doing anyting.  When you have && for example that is a boolean expression not a bitwise logical, so perhaps this is a typo?

the `val&(HIGH<<i)` though is pretty simple, again you should have posted what HIGH was defined as, lets assume it is a 1 since that makes the most sense relative to the rest of the code.  There is a loop i that goes from 0 to 7.  so that means that you are anding (bitwise) with `1<<0` and then `1<<1` and then `1<<2` and so on.  `1<<0` is just 1 right?  so `val&(1<<0)` is the same as val&0x01.  `1<<1 = 0x02` so val&0x02.  this code is one bit at a time isolating the individual bits in val.  you understand that if for example val is 0x07 then 0x07&0x02 = 0x02?  you line each bit up 0x07 = 0b00000111, 0x02 = 0b00000010

```
 00000111
&00000010
=========
 00000010
```

you look at this vertically isolate one column at a time and use the AND truth table which basically says the result is 0 unless both operands are a 1, there is one column where both operands are a 1 so the result for that column is a 1, the rest of the columns one or the other operand or both is a zero so the result is zero for that column.

```
 00000111
&00000100
=========
 00000100

 00000111
&000010000
=========
 00000000
```

Increment i two more times and evaluate against a val of 0x07 and you see what is happening at least with the `val&(HIGH<<i)` assuming that HIGH is a 1, if HIGH is a 0 then you will always get zeros come out of this code.

If you are wanting to and with a walking one why dont you just do val&HIGH, so again this doesnt make sense unless that peripheral or what is on the other end of that port desires this one bit at a time thing.

The double bang (!!) looks like a logical operation to me and has no business here IMO.

A single bang is a logical operation

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HIGH 1

int main ( void )
{

    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char PORTD;
    unsigned char val;

    PORTD=0;

    val=3;
    {
        printf("0x%02X\n",val);
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            PORTD |= !(val & (HIGH << i));
            printf("PORTD 0x%02X\n",PORTD);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The hope here would be that we know the compiler will generate 0x00 for a false, but what does it generate for a true?  0x01, 0xFF, the C language probably has a definition.  So the above code is genrating a bitstream based on our value

```
PORTD 0x00
PORTD 0x00
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
```

In the lsbit position, the the loop tickles a clock.

My personal preference would not be to play games with the C language spec, but be explicit to what you want to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HIGH 1
int main ( void )
{

    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char PORTD;
    unsigned char val;

    PORTD=0;

    val=3;
    {
        printf("0x%02X\n",val);
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            PORTD |= (~(val>>i))&1;
            printf("PORTD 0x%02X\n",PORTD);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}        

PORTD 0x00
PORTD 0x00
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
PORTD 0x01
```

using all bitwise operations, no boolean true/false operations.

Wondering if they were trying to do two boolean nots in a row to shift the not-zero bit to the zero bit position or something...instead for lsbit first or 7-i for msbit first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HIGH 1
int main ( void )
{

    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char PORTD;
    unsigned char val;

    PORTD=0;

    val=3;
    {
        printf("0x%02X\n",val);
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            PORTD |= (val>>i)&1;
            printf("PORTD 0x%02X\n",PORTD);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: so you can understand I hope that the msbit first else condition is walking a one from 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0  the lsbit first 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 as far as the bit the and is isolating, so this is trying to isolate one bit at a time, perhaps a bit shifter.  but as my simple program demonstrates (if you make HIGH  a 1, it doesnt isolate bits at least with another compiler, so if this was portable C it doesnt make much sense).